# how can i pass the data of the first form to the second one without recording those data on the database yet?

Tags: php, html

I have 2 forms on my project and their data must be recorded on the same row with the same database, so when you click the next button on the first form, the user will be directed to the second one, but I want not to record first its values on the database, because records/data of the first and the second form must be of the same row and I want them to be inserted on my database when you hit the save button on the second form, the issue here is that, how can i pass the data of the first form to the second one without recording those data on the database yet?
Can anyone help me?Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: hidden form fields or sessions

Comment: You can store the 1st form values in `$_SESSION` vars, or as hidden inputs in the 2nd form

Answer (score 0):

form1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])):
    header("Location: http://mysite.ext/form2.php");
else:
?>
<form action="form2.php" method="POST" name="form1">
    <input type="name" name="name"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

form2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])):
    header("Location: http://mysite.ext/form1.php");
elseif(isset($_POST['password'], $_SESSION['name'])):
    echo 'Thank you', $_SESSION['name'] ,'. We will verify your password, ', $_POST['password'],' now.';    
else:
?>
<form action="form2.php" method="POST" name="form2">
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding sir! but supposing, I want to record those values on a database using the INSERT INTO function of PHP, how can i do that?

Comment: @user3226202 You need to establish a connection to the database, then you can perform `SQL` logic in `elseif(isset($_POST['password'], $_SESSION['name'])):` of `form2.php`